# Почему пузырьковая сортировка справа налево работает медленнее?

Tags: java, сортировка, производительность

Написал две сортировки пузырьковых для массивов. и та которая идет справа налево (reverced) рабротает раза в полтора два медленнее. не пойму в чем дело

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавил скрин с кодом

Comment: А если замеры переставить местами эффект сохраняется? И еще, какой размер массива и как вы его заполняете перед первой и второй сортировками?

Comment: Разамер массива я ввожу с клавиатуры, тестировал на 100 000.
массив задается случайным образом. ну по сути как таковой первой и второй сортровки нет. просто я в этом блоке с замером вручную меняю вызов функции на другой и запускаю заного. Код не знаю как тестом добавлять

Comment: @ЛевТолстой `Код не знаю как тестом добавлять` - берете, копируете из программы и вставляете сюда. Вы же умеете копипаст? ([Как-форматировать-код-в-вопросах-и-ответах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5860/)) .......иначе вопрос ни о чем

Comment: 100000 это и в самом деле немало... Могу предположить, что в случае просмотра от меньших адресов к большим мы наблюдаем эффект опережающего чтения данных в CPU-cache  из RAM (в современных процессорах есть как предсказание переходов, так и предсказание обращения к памяти).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело не в сортировке, а в обходе массива.

Существует огромное количество холивара на тему: *какой цикл быстрее - прямой или обратный*, например:

1. [Reverse loop versus Forward loop](https://www.mkyong.com/java/reverse-loop-versus-forward-loop-in-performance-java/) - просто сравнение
2. [Why reverse loops are not faster](https://arnaudroger.github.io/blog/2017/06/15/forward-vs-backward-loop.html) - с сравнением дизассемблированных кусков
3. [Why reverse loops are faster](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/6h703p/why_reverse_loops_are_faster/) - дискуссия на пару страниц убористого текста

Ну и т.д.

Применительно к нашему случаю, поскольку производительность пузырьковой сортировки `O(N^2)`, то потеря производительности в цикле квадратично сказывается на общем результате.

Подозреваю, что на другом процессоре/языке/компиляторе результат может быть  противоположным.